# RepeatWhen alternative if observable is not completed?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

**I would like to manually retry a observable with last value emitted.**

I know of retry and repeat operators, however those afaik work only for errored and completed observables. My observable is never endling so this doesnt work. Id like to ask if there is a way other than this janky setup

```
queryObservable
    .donNext(query -> lastQuery = query)
    .mergeWith(repeatTriggerRelay)
    .switchMap(query -> getData_NeverCompletingObservable(query));

void rerun() {
    repeatTriggerRelay.onNext(lastQuery)
}
```

Is there maybe a overload of replay() I dont know of? Thanks

Comment: Perhaps use a `BehaviorSubject` only, signal a fresh query via `onNext` and signal a retry via `onNext(subject.getValue())`?

Comment: Okay that will work but is still a bit janky in my mind. Something like replayWhen() to resubscribe the upstream would be more elegant, since youre now the maintainer and everything :). Thanks

Comment: Two things: 1) naming a non-existent operator doesn't magically make it appear; 2) there us usually more to the context and lifecycle of custom operators to be considered beyond the basic expectation people post.

Comment: I know, it was just tongue in cheek.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BehaviorSubject` should be a simple solution:

```
BehaviorSubject<String> querySubject = BehaviorSubject.create();

querySubject
.switchMap(query -> getData_NeverCompletingObservable(query))
.subscribe(/* ... */);

querySubject.onNext("initial query");

void rerun() {
    querySubject.onNext(querySubject.getValue());
}
```